# how to load the splitViewController detailViewController to firstDetailViewController in an other class

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have UISplitView with many detailViewControllers it works fine but problem is that when i from any of the detailViewController move to LoginViewController and then back then i want that UIsplitViewController should have detailView controller which is firstViewController

here is the tableView did select method for RootViewController

```
    [self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
[viewControllerArray removeLastObject];


if (row == 0) {


    self.firstDetailViewController=[[[FirstDetailViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.firstDetailViewController];
    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.firstDetailViewController;







  }

if (row == 1) {



    self.secondDetailViewController=[[[SecondDetailViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.secondDetailViewController];
    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.secondDetailViewController;
}

if (row == 2) {
    self.myLearningViewController=[[[MyLearningViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.myLearningViewController];
    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.myLearningViewController;
}


if (row == 3) {
    self.communityViewController=[[[CommunityViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.communityViewController];
    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.communityViewController;
}


if (row == 4) {
    self.reportsViewController=[[[ReportsViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.reportsViewController];
    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.reportsViewController;
}




if (row == 5) {


    self.walkInViewController=[[[WalkInViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.walkInViewController];

    //self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.secondDetailViewController;

    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.walkInViewController;


}

if (row == 6) {


    self.postDataViewController=[[[PostDataViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

    [viewControllerArray addObject:self.postDataViewController];


    self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.postDataViewController;


}



[[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO];    


[self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
[viewControllerArray release];
```

I want when login button is clicked then it should set the detailViewController of rootViewCOntroller to firstDetailViewController

```
    -(IBAction)loginButton{

       }
```

Comment: logiviewcontroller is seperate viewcontroller ?

Comment: @Kirtimali yes loginviewcontroller is a separate view controller

Comment: when app lunch you want to display loginviewcontroller right ?

Comment: yes it works fine when app launches it shows login screen but i want that when detailViewController is secondViewController and i go to LoginViewController and then click on loginButton then it moves secondViewDetailViewController i want it to move to firstDetailViewController

Answer (score 0):

back to login

```
 appDelegate.window.rootViewController=appDelegate.self.loginviewcontroller;
    [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

login to detailviewcontroller is alreading  working you

Comment: this will go to loginViewController i want that using this it should move to splitViewController but splitViewController  should be rloaded

Comment: when screen loads simple it shows splitViewCOntroller when i click on row 2 it shows secondViewController  then you click login button then you should move to firstDetailViewController